# Encrypt & Decrypt ConnectionString on Multiple Devices

Tags: c#, uwp

## Problem

I am developing an application on UWP, where I use an Azure Directory Table Storage (So I must encrypt the connection string).

It must be encrypted once, but it must be decrypted on a different device.

How & Where can I store the encryption key?

Which algorithm should I use to do that?

### Tried

I tried the RSA algorithm, that I found here: http://www.japf.fr/2013/05/rsa-cryptography-between-a-winrt-and-a-dotnet-app/

But I can't store the keys in a JSON file...  I didn't understand why

### Expected

I want to encrypt the connection string in a config file that I'll share on other device and decrypt it on them as well.

Comment: What? Why are you sharing the config file. Each device should use its own config file  for the conneciton string, and you can encrypt it using the Machine Key and some other unique piece of information

Comment: Have you looked at the Azure Key Vault - it's an Azure Secrets store.  If your clients are all on Windows, consider using an RSA Key Container (I'm assuming that there's a UWP api for accessing that on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

About the RSA key : 
Finally I used an RSA algorithm to encrypt it, the public key will be in a config file and the private key will be stored in the local KeyVault of the application.

I just transform the byte array into an Hexadecimal String to store it like a string in a JSON file.

```
using System.Linq;

public static byte[] HexToByteArray(string s)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
        }

        public static string ByteArrayToHex(byte[] b)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(b).Replace("-", "");
        }
```